# First update of component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm quite new at React. I have main component and child component containing table. On componentDidmount I send request to API and receive data which I render in table. It is my first update of child component. Then I can add and delete rows from table and after one of this event my app shows notification (via componentDidUpdate). Unfortunatelly notification appear after receiving inital data which is not what I want.

```
var App = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function(){
    return {
        users:[],
        display: "none",
        currentId : 3,
    }
},
componentDidMount: function() {
    var that = this;
    this.serverRequest = 
      axios
        .get(API_URL + "/users")
        .then(function(result) {  
            that.setState({
            users: result.data
          });
        });
},
render: function(){
    return (
        <div className="container-fluid">
            <NotificationSystem ref="notificationSystem" />
            <div>
                <button className="btn btn-info" onClick={this.handleClick}>Add user</button>
            </div>  
            {this.manageForm()}
            <UsersTable data={this.state.users} onDeleteUser={this.deleteUser} addNotification={this._addNotification} />

        </div>
    );
}
});

var UsersTable = React.createClass({
renderRows: function() {
    var that = this;
    var rows;
    if(this.props.data.length !== 0){
        rows = this.props.data.map(function(row){
        return <UsersRow key={row.id} data={row} onDeleteUser={that.props.onDeleteUser} />
        })
    } else {
        rows = <UsersPlaceholder />;
    }
    return rows;
},
shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
    return nextProps.data !== this.props.data;
},

componentDidUpdate: function (prevProps, prevState) {
    this.props.data.length > prevProps.data.length ? this.props.addNotification('User was added','success') : this.props.addNotification('User was deleted','error');
},

render: function(){

    return (
            <table className="table">   
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>id</th>
                        <th>name</th>
                        <th>e-mail</th>
                        <th>del</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody> 
                    {this.renderRows()}
                </tbody>    
            </table>
    ); 
}

});
```

Is there any posibility to "catch" first update of table component in order to stop showing notification?

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: Done, I want to fire addNotification function only when adding or deleting rows by user (always but not during first update)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like below code it will work for me

```
var App = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function(){
    return {
        users:[],
        display: "none",
        currentId : 3,
        callonUpdate : true,
    }
},
deleteUser:function( id ){
        var data = [{id:2,name:"Ahmad ali"}];
        this.setState({
            users: data
          });
},
toggleUpdate:function() {
            console.log("update");
        this.setState({
            callonUpdate: true,
          });
},

componentDidMount: function() {
        var data = [{id:1,name:"shahid ahmad"},{id:2,name:"Ahmad ali"}];
    this.setState({
            users: data,
            callonUpdate : false
          });
},
render: function(){
    return (
        <div className="container-fluid">
            <UsersTable data={this.state.users} checkonCall = {this.state.callonUpdate} togglecallonUpdate = {this.toggleUpdate} onDeleteUser={this.deleteUser} />

        </div>
    );
  }
 });



var UsersTable = React.createClass({
delete : function( id ) {
        this.props.onDeleteUser(id);
},
renderRows: function() {
    var that = this;
    var rows;
    if(this.props.data.length !== 0){
        rows = this.props.data.map(function(row){
        return <tr>
                    <td>{row.id}</td>
                    <td> {row.name} </td>
              <td onClick={this.delete.bind(this,row.id)}>Delete </td>
              </tr>
        },this)
    } 
    return rows;
},

shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
    return nextProps.data !== this.props.data;
},

componentDidUpdate: function (prevProps, prevState) {
    console.log(this.props.checkonCall);
    if(this.props.checkonCall) {
    this.props.data.length > prevProps.data.length ? console.log('User was added') : console.log('User was deleted');
    }

    this.props.togglecallonUpdate();

},

render: function(){

    return (
            <table className="table">   
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>id</th>
                        <th>name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody> 
                    {this.renderRows()}
                </tbody>    
            </table>
    ); 
}

});
ReactDOM.render(
 <App  />,
 document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: Thanks, my solution is quite close to yours. In App Component I set callonUpdate : false in Initial State. Toggle function is similar to yours. In UsersTable component in componentDidUpdate: 
    
  if (this.props.tableNotification){ 
   this.props.data.length > prevProps.data.length ? console.log('User was added','success') : console.log('User was deleted','error');
  }
  else
  {
   this.props.updateNotification();
  }

Comment: magnat then please mark my solution if your problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly (you don't want initial population to add a notification), you can check that previous props weren't empty in your `componentDidUpdate` method:

```
componentDidUpdate: function (prevProps, prevState) {
    this.props.data.length > prevProps.data.length && prevProps.data.length > 0 ? this.props.addNotification('User was added','success') : this.props.addNotification('User was deleted','error');
}
```

This won't handle cases where all users are deleted and another is then added though. To do that, you could set a property in state on ajax success, pass that to the child component, and update it in parent state on an update from the child.

Answer (score 0):

Actually You misunderstand the concept According to React Js official documentation .

- componentDidMount()
  Invoked once, only on the client (not on the server), immediately after the initial rendering occurs. At this point in the lifecycle, you can access any refs to your children (e.g., to access the underlying DOM representation). The componentDidMount() method of child components is invoked before that of parent components.
  You will load you inital data in componentDidMount which actually call after you component is rendered to load your initial data you should use componentWillMount()

componentWillMount will immediately before the initial rendering occurs. If you call setState within this method, render() will see the updated state and will be executed only once despite the state change.

change componentDidMount with componentWillMount to load your inital data it will solve you problem

Comment: Your solution is what I was thinking about.Onthe other hand React official documentations tells about fetching data in componentDidMount and I don't know what is the best practise.

Comment: check this link
https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html

Comment: Exacly this link I mentioned.Fetch data in componentDidMount. When the response arrives, store the data in state, triggering a render to update your UI.